# explain the proof for an expression for $e^x$ using the binomial theorem

Tags: exponential-function

Below is the  proof for an expression for the $e^x$ using the binomial theorem. Could someone explain the second step? where we as n tends to infinity
$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\pars{1 + {1 \over n}}^{n} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{1 \over n}^{k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k!}
\,{n! \over \pars{n - k}!n^{k}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k!}
\,{\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n} \over
\bracks{\root{2\pi}\pars{n - k}^{n - k + 1/2}\expo{-\pars{n - k}}}n^{k}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k!}\,{\expo{-k} \over
\bracks{n^{-k}\pars{1 - k/n}^{n}\pars{1 - k/n}^{1/2 - k}}n^{k}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k!}\,{\expo{-k} \over
\bracks{n^{-k} \times \expo{-k} \times 1}n^{k}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k!}}}
\end{align}

Comment: It seems that they are using Stirling's approximation for the factorial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Comment: @ player3236 thank you